# setting cron jobs in node js for date range

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am working on a project where I need to send emails on the date which is in between two selected dates along with specific week days like only Monday and Thursday

The cron syntax is:

**0 * * * * ***

And the allowed values should be between below options

1. Seconds: 0-59
2. Minutes: 0-59
3. Hours: 0-23
4. Day of Month: 1-31
5. Months: 0-11
6. Day of Week: 0-6

I tried using **node-schedule - npm**. See my code below

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({ start: obj.start_date, end: obj.end_date, dayOfWeek: obj.dayOfWeek, hour: obj.hour, minute: obj.minute, second: 1 }, function(params){
         console.log(params);
    }.bind(null, obj));
```

I am able to run the jobs on dates but its not persistent. Whenever I make changes and starts the server it resets the scheduled jobs.

So how can I set a cron job which will run for specific dates(or date range) on selected days(Monday, tuesday etc)?

Comment: for node-schedule you need to have your server running all the time. You should look for the documentation of agenda if you want your jobs to be scheduled even when your server is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the work around on this. As I stored cron jobs in cache and whenever the server restarts, pushed them in to the cron again.